# What does the information gain measure show?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, data-modeling

I am busy using the `fSelector` package in r to measure information gain using the information.gain function.

I am a  unsure of what the output is giving me as there are minuses, I understand the output on the iris dataset.

```
weights <- information.gain(cross_over ~ age + max_stake_scale + current_loyalty_status + lifespan + early_hours + morning + afternoon + evening, df
```

The output is:

```
attr_importance
age                           0.000000e+00
max_stake_scale               0.000000e+00
current_loyalty_status        2.968854e-04
lifespan                      1.523364e-02
early_hours                   0.000000e+00
morning                       0.000000e+00
afternoon                     0.000000e+00
evening                       0.000000e+00
```

The response variable is binary, cross or not, yes or no. I am unsure of what the  important features are please.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information gain tells you how much information you gain by getting to know the value of a specific feature. In the case of a binary classification problem, you need 1 Bit of information to make the classification (as there are two possible outcomes); i.e. the maximum information gain for a specific feature is 1.

In your case, the information gain for almost all of the features is 0, meaning that knowing their value doesn't help at all with deciding which class the datum has. The non-zero values denote the most important (albeit still quite uninformative) features -- `lifespan` and `current_loyalty_status`. The minuses are simply part of the exponential notation, i.e. `2.968854e-04` means `2.968854 * 10^-4` or `0.0002968854`.

Comment: Thanks @Lars, so am I using the wrong feature selection method? Or should i normalise the data before doing this?  Also, are you saying the lifespan and current_loyality_status are the most important features for the model? I have a few more features too, which are a mix of binary and categorical features, although I only uploaded a few too get information about the values. Thanks

Comment: No, you're using the method as intended and you're getting valid output. I'm telling you how to interpret the output.

Comment: Arr brilliant, thank you - so current loyalty status is the most important features and the ones at 0 are less important. Thank you

Comment: In particular the ones with 0 don't tell you anything. They are useless.